# Me queda un border de los lados

Tags: css

Este es el código: me queda un border de los lados que no sé cómo quitarlo. He usado también SASS, he tratado quitando los padding y poniéndole boxsizing borderbox y no me funciona.

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-image: url(../img/bg1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.contenedor {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.header .logo img {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header .logo img {
    width: 500px;
  }
}

.header .nav {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 15%;
          flex: 0 0 15%;
}

.header .nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.header .nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.header .nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.hero {
  padding: 3rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.hero .lata {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 40%;
          flex: 0 1 40%;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .hero .lata {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
}

.hero .titulo {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .hero .titulo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

.hero .titulo h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: .1rem .1rem #333;
}

.hero .titulo h1 span {
  color: #039b39;
  background-color: #FFDF00;
}

.hero .titulo .boton {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid  white;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background: #13eb13;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero .titulo .boton:hover {
  background-color: #039b39;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.main .linea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #039b39;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.main .hero-2 {
  background: url(../img/hero-2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding: 0;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sass/app.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,400;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Sprite</title>
</head>

<body >

    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <i class="fas fa-user" style="color: white;"></i>
                <li><a href="#">Resgistrarse/Iniciar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="hero">
        <div class="titulo">
            <h1>
                tu sprite de siempre con <span>nueva imagen</span>
            </h1>

            <button class="boton" value="">Descubrelo aquí</button>
        </div>

        <div class="lata ">
            <img src="img/latauno.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <main class="main">
        <div class="linea"></div>
        <div class="hero-2">
           
        </div>
    </main>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: Este es el error los borders de los lados]

Comment: Trata de poner un padding en el css a el body con la cantidad que deseas, no se me ocurre otra cosa

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto los distintos navegadores agregan estilos personalizados a cierto elementos del `HTML`.

En este caso, el problema es que el `body` o el `html` tiene margen, por lo que habría que sacarselo.

**Ejemplo:**

```css
/* ACA sacamos los estilos por defecto */
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-image: url(../img/bg1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.contenedor {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.header .logo img {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header .logo img {
    width: 500px;
  }
}

.header .nav {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 15%;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
}

.header .nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header .nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.header .nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.hero {
  padding: 3rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hero .lata {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 40%;
  flex: 0 1 40%;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .hero .lata {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
}

.hero .titulo {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .hero .titulo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

.hero .titulo h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: .1rem .1rem #333;
}

.hero .titulo h1 span {
  color: #039b39;
  background-color: #FFDF00;
}

.hero .titulo .boton {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background: #13eb13;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero .titulo .boton:hover {
  background-color: #039b39;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.main .linea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #039b39;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.main .hero-2 {
  background: url(../img/hero-2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding: 0;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sass/app.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,400;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Sprite</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <i class="fas fa-user" style="color: white;"></i>
        <li><a href="#">Resgistrarse/Iniciar sesión</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="hero">
    <div class="titulo">
      <h1>
        tu sprite de siempre con <span>nueva imagen</span>
      </h1>

      <button class="boton" value="">Descubrelo aquí</button>
    </div>

    <div class="lata ">
      <img src="img/latauno.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <main class="main">
    <div class="linea"></div>
    <div class="hero-2">

    </div>
  </main>


</body>

</html>
```